# $(":not(selector)") in plain/ vanilla javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6

How can I write `$(":not(selector)")` in plain javascript?

jQuery:

```
var links = $('a:not(.not-lightbox-item a)', this);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="links">
    <div class="not-lightbox-item">
        <a href="projects.html" class="button-back">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-hand-left glyphicon-circle-arrow-leftx" title="Back"></span>
        </a>

        <h2 class="heading item-heading">(Title) Ways of Something</h2>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet <a href="#">Excepteur sint occaecat</a> cupidatat non proident</p>
    </div>

    <a href="images/banana.jpg" title="Banana">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/banana.jpg" alt="Banana">
    </a>
    <a href="images/apple.jpg" title="Apple">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/apple.jpg" alt="Apple">
    </a>
    <a href="images/orange.jpg" title="Orange">
        <img src="images/thumbnails/orange.jpg" alt="Orange">
    </a>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll`.

Comment: document.querySelector(":not(yourselectors)")

Comment: Upvoting question. It's legit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not toggle a class which has the selector applied to it in in pure CSS?

```
.className {
  color: blue;
}

var myitem = document.querySelector('.item')
myitem.classList.toggle('className');
```

I would resort to :not only if I had no control over the HTML.

Comment: thanks. i think I'll go for `links = this.getElementsByClassName('lightbox-item');` instead.

Answer (score 17):

use `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` as the solution :

```
//returns first element matching
document.querySelector("a:not(.not-lightbox-item a)");

//returns all elements matching
document.querySelectorAll("a:not(.not-lightbox-item a)");
```

However @George Katsanos is right, it is clearer (and probably faster) to use a class like `.lightbox-item` than a double negation like `a:not(.not-lightbox-item a)`

Comment: so many nasty people today!

Comment: not working in typescript / shadowDom.